# Accord avec des noms collectifs

Tags: accord

Une troupe de soldats **italienne** / **italiens**.

L'adjectif peut s'accorder soit avec le collectif soit avec son complément.

Quelle est la différence de sens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La phrase :

> Une troupe de soldats italienne

choque un peu l'oreille, mais à supposer qu'elle soit utilisée, les soldats pourraient être des citoyens d'autres pays, comme peuvent l'être des légionnaires de la Légion étrangère en France.

On peut éviter la collision de genres avec :

> Une troupe italienne de soldats

Comment: J'ai vu cet example dans le livre Grammaire française  (Livio mémo). Merci pour la réponse complète.